# How can I add a consistent left margin to a checkbox label?

Tags: html, css, web, frontend

I am working in a situation where I cannot easily modify my HTML, so I need a CSS solution to my margin/padding problem below.

**Code**

HTML

```
<dd id="rr-element">
   <label for="rr-1">
      <input type="checkbox" value="1" id="rr-1" name="rr[]">
      Do you agree to these terms of service? Note that agreeing to these terms of service may allow us unfettered access to your bank account, wordly possessions, and everything else you hold dear in this world.
   </label>
</dd>
```

CSS

```
dd {
    width: 300px;
}

dd label input {
   margin-right: 10px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/T86h8/403/

**Output**

Current

[image: current]

Desired

[image: desired]

**Does anyone know how I can go from my current configuration to my desired configuration (see images) using a CSS only solution?**

Thanks all.

Comment: I don't know if this is acceptable with your layout, but check this out http://jsfiddle.net/Lp6a4de8/

Comment: Nice solution Justin. Feel free to migrate this to an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Really hacky, but this will work:

```
dd {
    width: 300px;
}

dd label {
   padding-left:20px;
   display:block;
}

dd label input {
   margin-left:-20px;
   display:block;
   float: left;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/T86h8/407/

Comment: I like this solution the best since it doesn't disassociate the alignment of the first line from the rest of the lines. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Use `display:table` and `display:table-cell`

http://jsfiddle.net/T86h8/405/

HTML:

```
<dd id="rr-element">
    <input type="checkbox" value="1" id="rr-1" name="rr[]">
    <label for="rr-1">Do you agree to these terms of service? Note that agreeing to these terms of service may allow us unfettered access to your bank account, wordly possessions, and everything else you hold dear in this world.</label>
</dd>
```

CSS:

```
dd {
    width: 300px;
    display: table;
}
dd label, dd input {
    display: table-cell;
}
dd label {
    padding-left: 10px;
}
```

Comment: I'm personally looking for a CSS-only solution due to some constraints, but  I think the solution you've provided is still valuable for many use cases.

Comment: Yes, sorry I missed the not easy to edit HTML part :(

Answer (score 1):

You can use a negative text indent.  Fiddle  [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Lp6a4de8/)

CSS

```
dd {
  width: 300px;
  background:#d7d7d7;
  margin-left:50px;
}

dd label input {
  margin-right:10px;
}
dd label {
  background: #fff;
  display: inline-block;
  text-indent: -28px;
}
```

Comment: This looks like it works, but it makes me a bit uncomfortable.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use a combination of `padding` and `absolute position`, like this:

```css
dd {
  width: 300px;
  padding-left: 30px;
  position: relative;
  margin:0;
}
dd label input {
  position: Absolute;
  left: 5px;
  top: 5px;
}
```

```html
<dd id="rr-element">
  <label for="rr-1">
    <input type="checkbox" value="1" id="rr-1" name="rr[]">Do you agree to these terms of service? Note that agreeing to these terms of service may allow us unfettered access to your bank account, wordly possessions, and everything else you hold dear in this world.
  </label>
</dd>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set a negative margin on the input:

```css
dd {
  width: 300px;
}
dd label input {
  margin-left: -16px;
}
```

```html
<dd id="rr-element">
  <label for="rr-1">
    <input type="checkbox" value="1" id="rr-1" name="rr[]">Do you agree to these terms of service? Note that agreeing to these terms of service may allow us unfettered access to your bank account, wordly possessions, and everything else you hold dear in this world.
  </label>
</dd>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is some adjusted CSS. Hope that helps.

```css
dd {
    width: 300px;
    position:relative;
}
dd label {
    display:block;
   margin-left : 20px;
}

dd label input {
   margin-left:-20px;
    float:left;
}
```

```html
<dd id="rr-element">
   <label for="rr-1">
      <input type="checkbox" value="1" id="rr-1" name="rr[]">
      Do you agree to these terms of service? Note that agreeing to these terms of service may allow us unfettered access to your bank account, wordly possessions, and everything else you hold dear in this world.
   </label>
</dd>
```